# jetpack compose, Items in Expanded TopAppBar(LargeTopAppBar) are cut off

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm using LargeTopAppBar and I want to when it in expanded form show a list of item in a LazyRow but the problem is that, in expanded form , the top part of the items in the list gets cut off. even it has space below.

[image: app screenshot]

here my code:

```
fun AppbarDemo() {

    val scrollBehavior = TopAppBarDefaults.enterAlwaysScrollBehavior(rememberTopAppBarState())
    val isCollapsed = remember { derivedStateOf { scrollBehavior.state.collapsedFraction > 0.5 } }
    val topAppBarElementColor = Color.White
    val collapsed = 22
    val expanded = 24
    val topAppBarTextSize =
        (collapsed + (expanded - collapsed) * (1 - scrollBehavior.state.collapsedFraction)).sp
   // val topBarSize = if (isCollapsed.value) 64.dp else 156.dp

    Scaffold(
        topBar = {
            LargeTopAppBar(
                title = {
                    Column(
                        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
                        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.Start
                    ) {
                        if (isCollapsed.value) {
                            Row(
                                verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                                horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                            ) {

                                if (isCollapsed.value) {
                                    Log.i("TaaAG", "anim: ")
                                    Box(contentAlignment = Alignment.Center) {
                                        StoryItem(
                                            story = Story(
                                                id = 1,
                                                userName = "",
                                                avatar = R.drawable.avatar
                                            ),
                                            size = 50,
                                            isTextVisible = false
                                        )
                                    }

                                    // Spacer for spacing between icon and title
                                    Spacer(modifier = Modifier.width(8.dp))

                                    Text(
                                        text = "My App",
                                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge,
                                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                                        modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
                                        fontSize = topAppBarTextSize
                                    )
                                }
                            }
                        } else if (!isCollapsed.value) {
                            ListSection()
                        }

                    }
                },
                navigationIcon = {
                    Row(
                        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
                        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                    ) {
                        IconButton(onClick = { }) {
                            Icon(
                                imageVector = Icons.Default.Menu,
                                contentDescription = "Toggle drawer"
                            )
                        }
                        if (!isCollapsed.value) {
                            Text(
                                text = "My App",
                                style = MaterialTheme.typography.titleLarge,
                                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                                modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp),
                                fontSize = topAppBarTextSize
                            )
                        }
                    }
                },
                actions = {
                    IconButton(
                        onClick = { /* Handle search icon click */ }
                    ) {
                        Icon(
                            imageVector = Icons.Default.Search,
                            contentDescription = "Search"
                        )
                    }
                },
//                modifier = Modifier.height(topBarSize),

                scrollBehavior = scrollBehavior,
                windowInsets = WindowInsets(0.dp),
                colors = TopAppBarDefaults.largeTopAppBarColors(
                    containerColor = Color.Blue,
                    scrolledContainerColor = Color.Blue,
                    navigationIconContentColor = topAppBarElementColor,
                    titleContentColor = topAppBarElementColor,
                    actionIconContentColor = topAppBarElementColor,
                ),
            )
        },
        modifier = Modifier.nestedScroll(scrollBehavior.nestedScrollConnection)
    ) { innerPadding ->
        LazyColumn(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(innerPadding)
        ) {
            items(30) {
                Text(
                    text = "some data",
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.headlineMedium,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(15.dp)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried adjusting the height dynamically, but the issue persists.

and here is LazyRow and its items:

```
fun ListSection() {
    Box(
        Modifier
            .background(color = Color.Blue)
    ) {
        LazyRow(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .wrapContentHeight()
        ) {
            items(10) {
                ListItem(60)

            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun ListItem(size: Int) {
    Column(
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Box {
            Box(
                Modifier
                    .height(size.dp)
                    .width(size.dp)
                    .padding(5.dp)
                    .border(
                        shape = CircleShape,
                        border = BorderStroke(
                            width = 2.dp,
                            brush = Brush.linearGradient(
                                colors = BorderGradient,
                                start = Offset(
                                    0f,
                                    0f
                                ),
                                end = Offset(
                                    100f,
                                    100f
                                )
                            )
                        )
                    ),
                contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
            ) {
                val decreasedSize = size - 20
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(R.drawable.avatar),
                    contentDescription = null,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(decreasedSize.dp)
                        .clip(CircleShape)
                )
            }
        }

        Text(
            text = "person",
            fontSize = 8.sp,
            color = Color.White,
            style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodySmall,
            textAlign = TextAlign.Center
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: For your ListItem(size: Int) try passing 58 instead of 60

Comment: Thanks but isn't there any approach to not change this size?

Comment: Well LargeAppBar is for providing additional space for large screen devices. I would suggest you to change it with collapsing toolbar implementation.